# Sorting a 2D ArrayList By Each Column

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I need some clarification on how to sort a 2D Array List based on the values stored in each column.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Random;


public class ArrayListSorter {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> myArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        int numInstances = 10;
        int numAttributes = 10;
        for(int i = 0; i< numInstances; i++){
            myArrayList.add(new ArrayList<Double>());
            for(int j = 0; j < numAttributes; j++){
                Random r = new Random();
                double val = r.nextDouble();
                myArrayList.get(i).add(val);
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(myArrayList, new Comparator<ArrayList<Double>>() {    
            @Override
            public int compare(ArrayList<Double> o1, ArrayList<Double> o2) {
                return o1.get(2).compareTo(o2.get(2));
            }               
        });
        for(int i = 0; i < numInstances; i++){
            System.out.println(myArrayList.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

I set up an isolated form of my problem, which sets up a 2D ArrayList filled with random doubles. I can then sort by the first column (or any column that I specify in my code). I'm struggling with figuring out how to iterate to the next column to re-sort by the values in the next column. I need to be able to perform a set of operations after I sort the ArrayList each time.

Comment: I currently have the code set to sort the ArrayList by the 3rd column, which is indicated by: return o1.get(2).compareTo(o2.get(2));

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom Comparator as follows -

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<ArrayList<Double>> {

    private final int index;

    public CustomComparator(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public int compare(ArrayList<Double> first, ArrayList<Double> second) {
        return first.get(index).compareTo(second.get(index));
    }
}
```

and then further use it with your code to sort sequentially based on the indexes as -

```
for (int j = 0; j < numAttributes; j++) {
    System.out.println("Sorting based on column " + (j+1));
    myArrayList.sort(new CustomComparator(j));
    for (int i = 0; i < numInstances; i++) {
        System.out.println(myArrayList.get(i));
    }
}
```